# Keeping an opened connection TCP/IP

Tags: delphi, sockets

I am using TClientSocket and TServerSocket to comunicate with a server the problem is that sometimes connection is lost either by the server issuing me the following exceptions : Error on WsaSend, acess violation etc or by the Client : Asychronious socket error.

Witch is the best method to recover from these errors and keep the connection open no mather what ?

Comment: I highly recommend Indy, not sure if socket components are still maintained...

Comment: Why do you think that changing to Indy will fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as "keeping the connection open no matter what". What if the cable gets cut? The best you can do is to send a heartbeat on some interval to let intermediate routers know you are still interested in using that connection, and to carefully handle all errors, and, if necessary, re-establish the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Great question... what you're receiving is **WSAECONNABORTED** (*Asynchronous Socket Error 10053*).

How did i prevent it from happening in MY code ? well, there's something called Keepalive, if you look carefully into the name, Keep-Alive, it meant to keep the connection alive, just send Null data to the connection (Can be One-way), that's all...

i made a Timer (named it TmrKeepAlive) and set its interval to 5000ms (5 seconds), [More info on KeepAlive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive).

Edit: Also, if you don't want to write your own KeepAlive mechanism, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372281/how-to-use-so-keepalive-with-tserversocket) out