# How to use SO_KEEPALIVE with TServerSocket?

Tags: delphi, sockets, winsock

Does the component has a set option property or i need to use setsockopt function ?

i want to enable the os built in Keep-alive instead of me having to write it myself... -.-"

so, my question is, inside the constructor where i create the instance of TServerSocket, how do i then enable this SO_KEEPALIVE option ?

thanks everyone.

Comment: KEEPALIVE isn't for server (listening) sockets, it is for client or accepted sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setsockopt to set SO_KEEPALIVE

```
implementation

uses
  WinSock;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.ClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  OptVal: DWORD;
begin
  OptVal := 1;
  if setsockopt(Socket.SocketHandle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, PAnsiChar(@OptVal), SizeOf(OptVal)) = SOCKET_ERROR then
    raise Exception.Create(Format('WinSock Error %d', [WSAGetLastError()]));
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 s := TServersocket.Create(Self);
 s.Port := 8090;
 s.OnClientConnect := ClientConnect;
 s.Open;
end;
```

Comment: to be honest, when i see this, i kinda laugh at myself, because i was thinking to inherit from TServerWinSocket and Create it with SO_KEEPALIVE or SOL_INVALID bitwise mask flags, lol.

question, how can i see it working in the background, this keep alive operation ?

Comment: Why did you use Integer as output buffer when it expects a pointer to a char ?

Comment: @user1803300: Because it actually does expect an Integer (actually, a LongBool). It is just that `setsockopt()` is defined in the API to take a pointer to a char, so a type-cast is needed.

Comment: @user1803300: To see the keep-alive in action, you need to keep the connection idle and then use a packet sniffer, like WireShark, to watch the network activity. However, `SO_KEEPALIVE` uses OS-defined timeouts that cannot be customized on a per-socket basis, only system-wide, and those timeouts are actually fairly large by default, so it may take up to a couple of hours to see keep-alive activity on the network. To shorten the timeouts, you can use `WSAIoctl()` with `SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS` instead, however `SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS` is only supported on Win2K and later.